# inline-block content over three columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to vertically align content over three columns (Bootstrap framework) I only want this effect on screen size columns, It stacks fine with col-xs-12 added.

HTML

```
    <div class="row sub-footer">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
        <a class="sub-footer-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>           
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">    
        <div class="sub-logo-text"><p>A designer and creative strategist specializing in new business ventures</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 fcred">
        <p class="fcred">&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> - <strong><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></strong> <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
    </div>  

</div><!-- /sub-footer -->
```

CSS

```
.sub-footer-brand {
display: block;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size: contain;
}

.sub-logo > div { 
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle; 
}

.sub-logo-text {    
padding-left: 20px;
border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.fcred { 
text-align: right;
padding-right: 20px;
line-height: 40px; 
}
```

This output three columns. A responsive image (background of div), a paragraph of text, and a sentence which is the website copyright/creds.

the paragraph appears to be the hardest, it can be more than one line depending on screen size, I want it to stay vertically centred beside the other two elements.

Comment: Would using offsets help, perhaps?  See here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: It would be best to put this into a jsfiddle with some placeholder content instead of your Wordpress functions because I can only guess at what you're ultimately trying to achieve right now.

Comment: I can't seem to get bootstrap to integrate into a js fiddle

Comment: Just add the Boostrap external source in JSfiddle to integrate or use Bootply.

Comment: thats the part i can't figure out, what css URI

Comment: Use a CDN like http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ to get css/js for jsfiddle; click to open the tab named **EXTERNAL RESOURCES** on the left panel in jsfiddle, copy and paste the css/js into the box and hit the plus then you should be good to go.

Comment: oh ok, https://jsfiddle.net/xd006cak/5/ it doesn't seem to act exactly as I have it

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- vertical-align: 50% for the image and sentence
- vertical-align: 50%; line-height: 25% for the paragraph

**References**

- [vertical-align, inline-block, and line-height](http://www.brunildo.org/test/va_lineheight_ibl.html)